# File disappeared dragging it from Windows host to Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, 17.10, drag-and-drop

Today  I encounter a problem when using VBox .What the concrete is that :

1. The version VBox I am using is *Version 5.2.2 r119230 (Qt5.6.2)*
2. The host machine is Windows 10 Education and the guest OS on VirtualBox is Ubuntu 17.10.
3. The problem is when I have installed the VBox_GAs_5.2.2 ,set the *Devices* -> *Drop and Drag* -> *Bidirectional*  and rebooted Ubuntu. I tried to drag a file to Ubuntu guest OS desktop . The file disappeared when the dragging was done.

The images are:

[image: drag file 'h.py' to Ubuntu]
<sup>**drag file 'h.py' to Ubuntu**</sup>

[image: after drag where is the picture?]
<sup>**After dragging the file where is the picture?**</sup>

Additionally , the Chinese characters '+复制' in the first picture are the word 'copy'.

Comment: A safer way is to **right-click and select copy** (instead of move). Then the original file will not be removed. If the drag and drop operation succeeds, you can remove the original file afterwards. Otherwise it is still there, and you can use another method to transfer the file, for example via a local network, when both the host and guest systems and connected and one of them has a server function, for example openssh-server or samba in Ubuntu.

Comment: When i have copied file in windows host and prepared to paste to VBox ,but there the light of *paste*  was dark , so couldn'tt paste .what's wrong ?

Comment: Behind the drag-and-drop tool, there must also be a mechanism for copying a file from the host operating system to the guest operating system. If there is no such mechanism that is connected to the drag-and-drop tool, it will not work.