# Direct copy and paste between host and guest machines?

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I wanted to enable copying and pasting between my host and guest machines, so I installed VirtualBox Guest Additions. As a result, I became able to copy and paste **text**, but still unable to share files.
According to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/696103/810971), one solution is to:

1. install VirtualBox Extension Pack
2. Establish a shared folder between both machines

This is not effective for me and I am trying to find a way for directly copying and pasting **files** between host and guest machines, either with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V or by dragging and dropping. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Related: [Virtualbox Drag N Drop isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333616/virtualbox-drag-n-drop-isnt-working) I'm not sure how current those answers are, though.

Comment: what about Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V ?

Comment: See also this link: [File disappeared dragging it from Windows host to Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020963/file-disappeared-dragging-it-from-windows-host-to-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox). I am not sure that there is a mechanism for sharing files this way. It may be best to establish a shared folder between both machines, even though you would like something simpler.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/09/copy-paste-virtualbox-host-guest-machines/#comment-41728